# Remove element from Iterator in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, iterator, arrayaccess

I'm dealing with a class that implements *ArrayAccess* **AND** *Iterator* (let's say `$a`) and, while looping through it with a `foreach`, I would like to remove/unset some elements (based on some `if` conditions).

```
foreach($a as $item) {
    if(mustBeRemoved()) {
        $a->remove($item);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem in my implementation is that this provoke an unexpected behaviour in the `foreach` loop, cause it will not be aware of the changes and will keep going and stopping prematurely regardless the element removed (or added).

Is there a good/elegant way to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a for loop and go backwards.

Comment: make $item a reference in the 'foreach' loop and just 'unset' it directly.

Comment: @RyanVincent I tried but i get a **" An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference"**. Sorry I didn't mention that I'm working on a class that implements *ArrayAccess* **AND** *Iterator*, not *ArrayIterator*. (got confused)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your problem when I implemented a class that implements an Iterator and ArrayAccess for testing purpose:

```
<?php
class a implements Iterator, ArrayAccess {
    public $items = array();
    private $index = 0;

    public function current() {
        return $this->items[$this->index];
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->index;
    }

    public function next() {
        ++$this->index;
    }

    public function rewind() {
        $this->index = 0;
    }

    public function valid() {
        return array_key_exists($this->index, $this->items);
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return array_key_exists($offset, $this->items);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->items[$offset];
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->items[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->items[$offset]);
    }

    public function remove($item) {
        foreach($this->items as $index => $itemsItem) {
            if( $itemsItem == $item) {
                unset($this->items[$index]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

$a = new a();
array_map(array($a, 'offsetSet'), range(0, 100), range(0, 100));

foreach($a as $item) {
    if( $item % 2 === 0 ) {
        $a->remove($item);
    }
}

var_dump($a->items);
```

If you implemented the iterator, change it making sure removing an item won't make the "a" instance return different items when "next" and "current" are called.

Otherwise, you can try this:

```
$mustBeRemoved = array();
foreach($a as $item) {
    if(mustBeRemoved()) {
        $mustBeRemoved []= $item;
    }
}
foreach($mustBeRemoved as $item) {
    $a->remove($item);
}
unset($mustBeRemoved);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate use also the key of the element:

```
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
  if(mustBeRemoved()) {
    unset($a[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I confused the implementation. My object is an implementation of *ArrayAccess* and *Iterator*, not *ArrayIterator*. It doesn't seem to work on this kind of object, the loop ends prematurely.

Answer (score -1):

Just a straigt forward approach:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($a as $item) {
    if(!mustBeRemoved()) {
        $tmp[] = $item;
    }
}
$a = tmp;
```

Collect all the items that shouldn't be removed and simply create a new array. In the end assign the temporary array to your old one.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I wasn't sure it was an ***elegant* solution**, cause the internal objects of my looped collection are quite memory expensive. And I wanted to avoid it cause relying on another collection would not be optimal for performance.

Comment: This approach will destroy the Iterator class. Iterator!=Array